# Unpacking a .tgz file in maven

Tags: maven, ant

Is there a maven plugin that can do this. Currently I am using the ant plugin but I was wondering if there was another way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the [tarball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28file_format%29) you are trying to unpack is a project dependency, then the [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) can do this.  Have a look at the [unpack goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Maven-copy-plugin#Archiving, specifically the unpack option:

- http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Maven-copy-plugin#Unpacking_archives:_.3Cunpack.3E

Answer (score 0):

There's no *standard* Maven plugin that can do that.

However, you can use the Maven [antrun](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) plugin to use the standard Ant tasks to do the unpacking for you. That's what I used when I had a similar issue.

There are quite a few privately developed Maven plugins that can unpack files, but they're not usually available in the standard public repositories, and I'd rather not be have my Maven build process dependent upon some third party repository. Too many times, I've had these repositories go down, and suddenly I am unable to do my build.

Answer (score 0):

The `maven-assembly-plugin` can create and unpack `.tar.gz` files.  I don't know if it recognizes the `.tgz` extension.